# how to solve "ssl certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate" in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: r, ubuntu, curl, openssl, rvest

I'm using `rvest` to scrape a website. I'm totally OK with other websites but this one is using another type of certificate I think. I've seen similar questions here and in github but no one could help me.
Any help is appreciated. 
My script is as follows:

```
url <- "https://search.codal.ir/api/search/v1/q?PageNumber=1&Symbol=%D9%81%D8%B3%D8%A7&Subject=%20&CompanyState=0&LetterType=6&TracingNo=-1&LetterCode=%20&FromDate=1395/01/01&ToDate=%DB%B1%DB%B3%DB%B9%DB%B8/%DB%B0%DB%B3/%DB%B1%DB%B6&AuditorRef=-1&YearEndToDate=&Publisher=false&Mains=true&Childs=false&Audited=false&NotAudited=true&Length=-1&Consolidatable=true&NotConsolidatable=true&CompanyType=1&Category=1"

data <- fromJSON(url)[[3]]
```

and the error is:

> "Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : 
>     SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate"

Comment: I'm on Firefox, and when I try that link I get a message "Warning: Potential Security Risk Ahead

Firefox detected a potential security threat and did not continue to search.codal.ir. If you visit this site, attackers could try to steal information like your passwords, emails, or credit card details." Are you sure this is the URL you want?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. yes I'm sure and I don't think that there is a potential risk because this a URL that many people use everyday without any issue. This is a search query that fetches companies financial statements. @camille

Answer (score 4):

This is a wrongly configured server (search.codal.ir). A friendly email to their admins could probably be considered.

The problem here is that this TLS server doesn't send a complete cert chain in the handshake, which it should according to standards. More specifically, it doesn't send the intermediate certificate. This is visible by posting "search.codal.ir" into SSL Labs test page and [the results are clear](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=search.codal.ir).

Intermediate certificates are certs that are sort of "in between" the root certificate (that exists in the CA store) and the server's own certificate.

This sometimes work better in browsers than with curl because

1. browsers typically *cache* the intermediate certs (which can be used by multiple hosts)
2. some browsers (like Chrome) supports features like AIA (Authority Information Access) which makes it able to download intermediate certificates on-demand. [RFC 5280 has the details](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.2.1).

The curl error message `unable to get local issuer certificate` almost always means this is what happened.

## Fixing it

The **real** and proper fix should be done by the server admins. This is a server setup problem.

## Working around it

You can download the intermediate cert manually and put it in your CA store, the PEM file you tell curl (or other client) to use when verifying the peer.

The SSL Labs page says the following about the missing intermediate cert:

```
Certum Organization Validation CA SHA2
Fingerprint SHA256: fd02362244f31266caff005818d1004ec4eb08fb239aafaaafff47497d6005d6
Pin SHA256: 51GveKNrpJjtGpXY5QDx03s3YTQwaQic6dWBqo3zX6s=
RSA 2048 bits (e 65537) / SHA256withRSA
```

(I couldn't find where to download it from)

## Don't do this

You *can* disable certificate verification completely which then will allow your program to continue. But you've then given up on all security and there are just sadness and tears going down that road. Only do that for experiments, never for production.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm not an experienced one in ssl stuff so could you please tell me what should I do to bypass this error?

Comment: Thank you, could you please specify the download link? I could not find it in ssl labs

Comment: Sorry, I changed the text now since I couldn't find a download either!

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
library(httr)
set_config(config(ssl_verifypeer = 0L))
```

Comment: Thank you Alexandre but you know, this method surprisingly doesn't work for me. I'm totally frustrated with this issue.